# OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine / ODBC compatible way to query only top row from a joined table with a 1-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, odbc

I'm using a 3rd party ODBC driver for a proprietary application.

I can run both of the following queries against the database using the proprietary application's other tools, but I need to find a way to rewrite this so that it will work against the ODBC driver.  On the back-end, the application uses SQL Server 2008.

I'm looking for another way to tackle the same problem that hopefully the ODBC driver will be able to understand.

Failed attempt 1 using CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT 
    po.Order_No
  , pol.Line_No
  , por.Release_No
  , por.Due_Date
  , por.Quantity
  , por.Quantity_Shipped
  , polp.Effective_Date
  , polp.Price_Change_Reason_Key
FROM Sales_v_PO_e po
INNER JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e pol
  ON pol.PO_Key = po.PO_Key
  AND pol.PCN = po.PCN
INNER JOIN Sales_v_Release_e por
  ON por.PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
  AND por.PCN = pol.PCN
CROSS APPLY 
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 Effective_Date, Price_Change_Reason_Key
        FROM Sales_v_Price_e
        WHERE PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
          AND PCN = pol.PCN  
          AND Active = 1
          AND Effective_Date <= por.Due_Date
        ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC, Add_Date DESC
      ) polp
WHERE polp.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
```

This throws the following error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyServer" returned
>   message "[Application][ODBC ODBC Report Data Source driver][OpenAccess
>   SDK SQL Engine]Syntax error in SQL statement. syntax error line 19 at
>   or after token CROSS.[10179]".

Failed attempt 2 using JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    po.Order_No
  , pol.Line_No
  , por.Release_No
  , por.Due_Date
  , por.Quantity
  , por.Quantity_Shipped
  , polp.Effective_Date
  , polp.Price_Change_Reason_Key
FROM Sales_v_PO_e po
INNER JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e pol
  ON pol.PO_Key = po.PO_Key
  AND pol.PCN = po.PCN
INNER JOIN Sales_v_Release_e por
  ON por.PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
  AND por.PCN = pol.PCN
INNER JOIN  Sales_v_Price_e polp
  ON polp.Price_Key = 
      (
        SELECT TOP 1 Price_Key
        FROM Sales_v_Price_e
        WHERE PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
          AND PCN = pol.PCN  
          AND Active = 1
          AND Effective_Date <= por.Due_Date
        ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC, Add_Date DESC
      )
WHERE polp.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
```

This throws the error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyServer" returned message "[Application][ODBC ODBC Report Data Source driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax error in SQL statement. syntax error line 35 at or after token ORDER.[10179]".

UPDATE:

Here is a 3rd attempt that worked in the SQL environment but failed with the ODBC driver.  This attempt leverages the incrementing integer key to get the last added record.

```
SELECT 
    po.Order_No
  , pol.Line_No
  , por.Release_No
  , por.Due_Date
  , por.Quantity
  , por.Quantity_Shipped
  , polp.Effective_Date
  , polp.Price_Change_Reason_Key
FROM Sales_v_PO_e po
INNER JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e pol
  ON pol.PO_Key = po.PO_Key
  AND pol.PCN = po.PCN
INNER JOIN Sales_v_Release_e por
  ON por.PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
  AND por.PCN = pol.PCN
INNER JOIN Sales_v_Price_e polp
  ON polp.Price_Key =
      (
        SELECT MAX(Price_Key)
        FROM Sales_v_Price_e
        WHERE PO_Line_Key = por.PO_Line_Key
          AND PCN = por.PCN  
          AND Active = 1
          AND Effective_Date <= por.Due_Date
      ) 
WHERE polp.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
```

Throws the error

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyServer" returned message "[Application][ODBC ODBC Report Data Source driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Column:PO_Line_Key not found.[10125]".

Comment: Both of these queries are syntactically correct on SQL Server.  Are you sure these are the queries that are getting passed?  It's complaining about a token `.[10179]` that's not in your code... and there aren't even 35 lines in your second query.

Comment: Ah, the token it was complaining about didn't show above because it was wrapped in tags...I'll fix the error messages, and it will make more sense.

Comment: Fixed the error messages...the actual tokens it was complaining about were "CROSS" in the first query and "ORDER" in the second.

Comment: what about creating these statements as views?

Comment: It's a 3rd party cloud application and I have no direct access to the database for the creation of views, procedures, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine does not support](http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/openaccess/alloa/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=sqlref/limitations.8.01.html) `CROSS APPLY` joins or sub-queries with `TOP` in them.  It does appear to allow the `ROW_NUMBER` function so maybe this would work:

```
SELECT 
    Order_No
  , Line_No
  , Release_No
  , Due_Date
  , Quantity
  , Quantity_Shipped
  , Effective_Date
  , Price_Change_Reason_Key
FROM 
    (select po.Order_No
      , pol.Line_No
      , por.Release_No
      , por.Due_Date
      , por.Quantity
      , por.Quantity_Shipped
      , polp.Effective_Date
      , polp.Price_Change_Reason_Key
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (PARTITION BY po.Order_No, pol.Line_No, por.Release_No
           ORDER BY Effective_Date DESC, Add_Date DESC) RowNum
    FROM Sales_v_PO_e po
    INNER JOIN Sales_v_PO_Line_e pol
      ON pol.PO_Key = po.PO_Key
      AND pol.PCN = po.PCN
    INNER JOIN Sales_v_Release_e por
      ON por.PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
      AND por.PCN = pol.PCN
    INNER JOIN  Sales_v_Price_e polp
      ON PO_Line_Key = pol.PO_Line_Key
      AND PCN = pol.PCN  
      AND Active = 1
      AND Effective_Date <= por.Due_Date
    ) o
WHERE RowNum=1
    and o.Effective_Date <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the documentation.  That will definitely come in handy.  Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work.  It appears that it doesn't like the references to the tables outside the subquery with this syntax.  Incidentally, this doesn't work in their SQL environment either (which is more direct) for the same reason.

Comment: When I run this through the ODBC connector I get "Column:PO_Line_Key not found."

When run in their SQL environment, I get "The multi-part identifier "pol.PO_Line_Key" could not be bound."  And the same for the fields pol.PCN and por.Due_Date.  That seems strange since referencing them in the subquery like that worked in the original examples.

Comment: Ah... yours worked against SQL Server because you are using the sub-query as a scalar... mine required a CROSS APPLY, which you can't use.  I edited my answer with another approach.