# Ingest Netsuite data to ADLS via ADF

Tags: azure, netsuite, azure-data-factory

One of my task includes ingesting Netsuite data to Azure ADLS via ADF. While I went ahead with installing required ODBC drivers in my Azure ADF IR and connecting via ODBC connector, Im getting SQL syntax error. One thing I noticed is that after setting up the linked services, the tables do show up, but in format `\u000 ( Role Name ) = \u000TABLE_NAME\u000`

**Error while Preview Data:**

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42000] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax Error in the SQL statement.[10104],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [42000] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Syntax Error in the SQL statement.[10104],Source=NQoa27.dll,'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like something wrong with your query statement. Either it is incorrect or there might be a limitation issue with [OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine](http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/openaccess/alloa/index.html) as discussed in this post - [OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine / ODBC compatible way to query only top row from a joined table with a 1-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340304/openaccess-sdk-sql-engine-odbc-compatible-way-to-query-only-top-row-from-a-joi)

Here is another related post, please review your query and see if all the statements/functions used are supported by OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine : [Syntax error when executing batch of SQL statements with OpenAccess ODBC client](https://progress-supportcommunity.force.com/s/article/6594)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a lot of grief and development time and look at https://www.tacticalconnect.com/. Its sole purpose is to push CSV results (from Saved Searches) to different endpoints.  Azure is one of them.  ON a scheduled basis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).